# Convert part of the values in rows in a data frame

Tags: r, replace, subset

I have a data frame which looks like this:

df

```
colA colB
0     0
1     1
0     1
0     1
0     1
1     0
0     0
1     1
0     1
```

I would like to convert a certain proportion of the 0 in colA to NA and a certain proportion of 1 in colB to NA

if I do this:

```
df["colA"][df["colA"] == 0] <- NA
```

all the 0 in columns A will be converted to NA, however I just want half of them to be converted

Similarly, for colB I want only 1/3 of the 1 to be converted:

```
df["colB"][df["colB"] == 1] <- NA
```

Expected output:

```
   colA colB
    0     0
    1     1
    NA    1
    0     1
    NA    1
    1     0
    0     0
    1     NA
    NA    NA
```

Comment: Which half/third?

Comment: not any specific values, can be just random

Comment: So the replacement to `NA` can be at any position, as long as the total is half of total `0` in `colA` and a third of total of `1` of `colB`?

Comment: yes, as long as the total is half of the total 0 or a third of the total 1, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way

```
tmp=which(df["colA"]==0)
df$colA[sample(tmp,round(length(tmp)/2))]=NA
```

similar for colB

```
tmp=which(df["colB"]==1)
df$colB[sample(tmp,round(length(tmp)/3))]=NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prodNA` from the `missForest` package

```r
set.seed(1)
library(missForest)
df[df$colA == 0, "colA"] <- prodNA(df[df$colA == 0, "colA", drop=F], noNA = 0.5)
df[df$colB == 1, "colB"] <- prodNA(df[df$colB == 1, "colB", drop=F], noNA = 1/3)
df

  colA colB
1   NA    0
2    1   NA
3    0   NA
4   NA    1
5   NA    1
6    1    0
7    0    0
8    1    1
9    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll contribute a `tidyverse` approach here.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(id_colA = ifelse(colA == 1,  NA, 1:n()),
              colA = ifelse(id_colA %in% sample(na.omit(id_colA), sum(!is.na(id_colA))/2), NA, colA),
              id_colB = ifelse(colB == 0, NA, 1:n()),
              colB = ifelse(id_colB %in% sample(na.omit(id_colB), sum(!is.na(id_colB))/3), NA, colB)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("id_"))
```